# Semi-asynchronous pipe

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, fifo

Assume I have the following pipe:

```
a | b | c | d
```

How can I wait for the completion of `c` (or `b`) in `sh` or `bash`? This means that script `d` can start any time (and does **not** need to be waited for) but requires complete output from `c` to work correctly.

The use case is a `difftool` for `git` that compares images. It is called by `git` and needs to process its input (the `a | b | c` part) and display the results of the comparison (the `d` part). The caller will delete input that is required for `a` and `b`. This means that before returning from the script, process `c` (or `b`) must terminate. On the other hand, I cannot wait for `d` because this means I'm waiting for user input.

I know I can write the results of `c` to a temporary file, or perhaps use a FIFO in `bash`. (Not sure if the FIFO will help, though.) Is it possible to achieve this without temporary files in `sh`?

**EDIT**

Perhaps it would be sufficient if I could find out the process ID of the `c` (or `b`) process in a reliable fashion. Then the whole pipe could be started asynchronously, and I could wait for a process ID. Something along the lines of

```
wait $(a | b | { c & [print PID of c] ; } | d)
```

**EDIT^2**

I have found a solution, comments (or still better solutions) are welcome.

Comment: You mean you want `d` to start processing `c`'s output only after `c` has completed? You don't want `d` to start processing each output line as it comes?

Comment: @terdon: No, `d` is free to start whenever it likes, but `c` needs to finish before I can move on.

Comment: That seems to be self-contradictory, if `d` can start when it likes, what exactly are you waiting for?

Comment: @terdon: Expanded to show use case.

Comment: If `d` does not use the output of `c` then it seems not to make any sense to make `d` part of the pipeline. But if `d` does use the input then `d` must work a while on its input after having read all of it for your approach to make any difference.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: `d` awaits user input and of course requires output of `c`.

Answer (score 6):

```
a | b | { c; [notify];} | d
```

The notification can be done e.g. by a signal to a PID which has been passed in an environment variable (`kill -USR1 $EXTPID`) or by creating a file (`touch /path/to/file`).

**Another idea:**

You execute the next process (the one to be able to start you are waiting for) from the pipeline:

```
a | b | { c; exec >&-; nextprocess;} | d
```

or

```
a | b | { c; exec >&-; nextprocess &} | d
```

Comment: Thanks. But then, creating a temporary file for the intermediate output is more verbose and easier to parse (for a human). Also, how do I avoid the race condition with the signal? ... I was hoping for a cleaner solution, but if this is the way to go, then so be it.

Comment: @krlmlr What race condition?

Comment: `notify` could be executed before I set up the signal trap. How can I make sure not to miss that signal?

Comment: @krlmlr You stop the script which calls the pipeline until it receives a signal itself which is sent after the `trap` has been defined.

Comment: Your edit: The pipe is called in a loop, over which I have no control. Unfortunately, `{ c; bg; }` or `{ c; exit 0; }` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @krlmlr How do you define "seem to work"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13226/discussion-between-krlmlr-and-hauke-laging)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
a | b | c | { (exec <&3 3<&-; d) &} 3<&0
```

(the fd 3 trick is because some (most) shells redirect stdin to /dev/null with `&`).

Answer (score 4):

In bash, you can use a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution). The command in the process substitution runs asynchronously, it is not waited for.

```
a | b | c > >(d)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is `bash` only, right -- no `sh` support?

Comment: @krlmlr Bash/zsh only (and ksh93 with a few modifications).

Answer (score 3):

This is what I have found by trial and error, with the help of Hauke's input:

```
a | b | { c; kill -PIPE $$; } | d
```

Equivalently:

```
a | b | ( c; kill -PIPE $$; ) | d
```

(The latter is more explicit, because `{}` will run in a subshell anyway if inside a pipe.)

Some other signals (including `QUIT`, `TERM` and `USR1`) work, too, however in this case the description of the signal is shown on the terminal.

I wonder if this is the original intention of the `PIPE` signal. According to [the manual](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/signals.htm):

> `SIGPIPE`: The `PIPE` signal is sent to a process when it attempts to write to a pipe without a process connected to the other end.

This means that when I artificially send a pipe signal to the subshell, it silently terminates, leaving the final consumer (`d`) alone.

This works in both `sh` and `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sponge` program from the "moreutils" package:

`a | b | c | sponge | d`

sponge will for the end of `c`'s output before piping it to `d`. Hope that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
a | b | c | (d ; cat > /dev/null)
```

So, when `d` finishes, the `cat` will absorb the rest of `c`'s output until it finishes.

Ok. After comments, I think the answer is to directly start `d` in the background.

Do:

```
a | b | c | (d &)
```

or use *Stephane Chazelas*'s solution if there are problems with `d` reading from *stdin*.

Comment: I'm afraid my use case is rather the other way round: `c` finishes earlier than `d`, and I have to wait until `c` finishes but don't care for `d`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What do you want to do when `c` finishes and `d` is still running? Kill `d`?

Comment: `d` has a GUI and can run until the user closes it.

Comment: OK... but this already happens. When `a`, `b`, and `c` finish their work, they close stdout and exit; and only `d` remains running. Do you want to send `d` to background when `c` finishes? Is that it?

Comment: Yes, `d` should be sent to the background once `c` finishes.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: The second pipe didn't work for me. I still have to test the "fd 3" trick.